# Migrate/Sync Data between tables of different Schemas

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamics-crm, database-replication

thanks for sparing some time by looking at my question. I am not sure if this is practical and already answered but i don't have words to search for so i will explain the problem here:

1. We have 2 Databases, "CRM" and "Reporting". "CRM" database is the primary database where we store all our data.
2. In "Reporting" db we have created 5 views that fetch data from "CRM" db tables at run-time and done some reporting on them. The separate database is because we are not allowed to created "Store Procedure/Views" in "CRM" db.
3. Now when we run our reports, based on Views that are in "Reporting" db they are very slow because of complex joins in the views and other computing logics. We have done the required indexing and things but that doesn't help much.

What i want to do is fetch data from "CRM" db using "Views" in the "Reporting" db and store them in some tables in "Reporting" and do a simple "select *from table" in reports. The tables will have the exact same structure as views in "Reporting" db.

**Questions:** I am not sure how the data updates/creates will be synced between "CRM" and "Reporting" tables provided that data will be fetch through views to keep the calculated/report ready data ?

Comment: Do you need this data to be super-real-time on the Reporting database or you can have it let's say 1 day old or something? If so, I would just have a stored procedure reading from the views once per day (or night, as it's best for your needs) and filling up the reporting tables.(You can then also index the new tables properly). This procedure would then run as a step in a SQL Agent Job.

Comment: @RigertaDemiri We don't want the data to be super-realtime, but we will want to have a scheduler that let's say will run after 1 hour.

Comment: Great, then you can just set up an Agent Job to do the work and you're set. Every hour you will get the new data. You will need to be careful though, to not override existing data (so you will implement a logic to only get new data based on the importing date or anything else).

Comment: Have you looked into Merge stored procedures with incremental loading. You have different choices ex: Merge Stored procedures, Triggers, SSIS incremental loading with look up, merge replication between databases etc..

Comment: @RigertaDemiri "so you will implement a logic to only get new data based on the importing date or anything else" that's my actual question :)